# Can you overwrite a Firebase reference?

Tags: reference, firebase, overwrite

I want to create a temporary reference such as:

```
var firebaseRef = new Firebase('httpX://reference.firebaseio.com/temp')
```

and then overwrite it once I receive a certain variable like this:

```
var firebaseRef = new Firebase('httpX://reference.firebaseio.com/variable')
```

When I try, the overwrite function seems to work at first: if I include

```
alert(firebaseRef)
```

in the function itself (after the overwrite attempt), it returns the new reference name but after the function runs, if I check firebaseRef again via console, it returns the old reference, and all subsequent calls go to the old ref.

Am I simply trying to do something not allowed by Firebase or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Most likely you are still referring to the initial reference. But that depends on the exact code. Can you write a single snippet, instead of separate lines?

Comment: I can't unfortunately, because I don't know the variable until after the app is initialized, and I have child references based on the reference in question, so the ref has to be defined as the DOM loads.

Comment: Unless you can show a snippet of code that reproduces the problem, it will be difficult to help. The lines above are not enough for that. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve